# Significant terms aggregation with parent sampler aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES 2 index with ~3m documents and I'm doing a significant terms aggregation on a relatively high-cardinality field (~1m unique values) with a classic power-law frequency distribution (a few of these unique values are very frequent and most of the others form a long tail of low counts).

This aggregation is prohibitively expensive and slow, so I started looking into ES 2's new [sampler aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) feature. It works as a parent aggregation that will make the child aggregation work on a sample of the data. However, I want to understand better how it works, as there's little documentation on the subject.

I'm using a `shard_size` parameter for the sampler aggregation of 200, and the results I get are wildly different from the unsampled significant terms aggregation. Also, sometimes the sampled aggregation does not return any results. So I'm trying to understand at which point in the process the sampling happens.

If `x` is one of the buckets in the significant terms aggregation and `y` is the size of the filtered corpus, then its significance measure is given by something like `significance of x in subset y = [ (count x in y / size y) / (x in corpus / size corpus) ] * [ (count x in y / size y) - (x in corpus / size corpus) ]` as per the definition of the JLH score.

Is the sampling applied immediately to the corpus before filtering or is it applied to the filtered set `y`? I'm trying to understand why sometimes my sampled aggregation returns no results when I know there should be some. I also noticed that if I increase the `shard_size` parameter of the sampler aggregation, I eventually get some results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lateness- only just come across this question :)

The significant_terms agg depends by default on having at least 3 instances of a term in results (see min_doc_count) before it is certain it might be useful.
If your sample size is too small you'll perhaps not satisfy this threshold for the selected terms. If you have too many shards as well that makes life more difficult as it spreads the answers to your questions around a network.
Small sample sizes are good though if your query is fuzzy - it focuses in on high-quality, high-signal results. The effects of these settings can be seen clearly here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azP15yvbOBA